# php shell command error GLIBCXX_3.4.9 not found

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, glibc, libreoffice

Im trying to execute shell command from php to convert files to pdf but i get this error.
Could someone explain me in details how to fix it?
Im not so good in linux(
and also if i execute command straight through terminal everything works.

```
    /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6:
    version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found 
    (required by /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../ure-link/lib/libuno_sal.so.3)
```

Answer (score 5):

> version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found

The problem is that in this environment, you are using `/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6` which is too old, and does not define the `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' version.

> if i execute command straight through terminal everything works.

In that case, you are likely using `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6`, which is (apparently) new enough.

Possible solutions:

1. Remove `/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6` and use `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6` everywhere (libstdc++.so.6 is supposed to be backwards-compatible, so in theory there should be no reason to use older version).
2. Un-set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `PHP` before invoking `oosplash`, so it uses the newer library.

Comment: Sir.. could you help me.. at :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888096/glibcxx-3-4-9-not-found-ubuntu

Comment: @Muhammad What more help do you need? Your question is an exact duplicate of this one, and the same solution/answer should fix it.

Comment: @EmpoyedRussian Sir.. i am new to `ubuntu` and `shell_exec` so i dont know how to remove `/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6` and use `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6` everywhere and Un-set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ... please help sir..

Comment: Sir please look at this is this the way to solve this: http://community.bitnami.com/t/libstdc-so-6-issue/20589

Comment: sir i have tried this.. but still it is not working: `sudo mv /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6.orig
`

Answer (score 0):

Try this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/63443384/12099812

1.add below line in your PHP file.

```
var_dump(shell_exec("whoami"));
```

you can find the username in your browser after clicking the url related to your PHP file

2.in your terminal

```
sudo vim /ect/sudoers

#in vim editor, add this line in your sudoers file
"username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"
#change username to that found in step one
```

3.change the exec cmd in your PHP file to

```
exec("sudo python3 urfilename.py")
```

The main reason for your problem maybe the root permission, so by changing your sudoers file, the error might be tackled.