# GLIBCXX_3.4.9 not found ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, converters, shell-exec

i am trying to convert `.doc` file to `.html` file using `shell_exec` command php..

for this i have written the below code:

```
  $result = shell_exec("soffice --headless --convert-to html /opt/lampp/htdocs/converter/public/uploads/resume/".$filename." 2>&1");
  echo $result;
```

but i am getting this when i run the project from the browser:

```
 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../ure-link/lib/libuno_sal.so.3) 
 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../ure-link/lib/libuno_sal.so.3)
```

please help i am new to `shell_exec` and `ubuntu`

Comment: How did you install Libreoffice?

Comment: @Tomdarkness sir actually i am not able to remember it, i googled and followed the instruction there...but unfortunately i forgot the website i have followed the instruction..please help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [php shell command error GLIBCXX\_3.4.9 not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20729067/php-shell-command-error-glibcxx-3-4-9-not-found)