# Reading live output of a python program using php

Tags: php, python, linux, real-time

I am making a PHP web page that executes a python program and while the python program is running, it displays the output in real-time. 
After following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107147/php-reading-shell-exec-live-output), this is the code that I am trying.

```
$cmd = 'python execs/reduction_code.py';
while(@ ob_end_flush());

$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
echo '<pre class="box">';

while(!feof($proc)){
    echo fread($proc, 4096);
    @ flush();
}

echo '</pre>';
pclose($proc);
```

After I start executing the program `reduction_code.py`, in every 30 seconds, it displays few print statements (telling about status of the program). The program takes approx 25 minutes to completely execute. This works well when i run the python program using terminal.

However, when i run this using the above php code, it doesn't show any output at all. The file `reduction_code.py` is executable and apache has the permission to execute and read it.

Also, when i run a simple python program to ping an address by replacing the value in `$cmd` as `$cmd = 'python execs/test.py';` , I get the expected real-time output of ping probes in my page.

`test.py` is:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ping", "-c", "10", "localhost"])
```

I am new to PHP and I have no idea why after running `reduction.py`, the page displays no output at all.

**EDIT 1** : When I use `$proc = popen($cmd.' 2>&1', 'r');` instead of `$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');` to access any error message returned by shell. I get this error message printed on my webpage(at the place where output was expected to appear).

```
Resource id #9/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/path.py:296: UserWarning: IPython parent '/root' is not a writable location, using a temp directory." using a temp directory."%parent)

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/config/configuration.py:687: ConfigurationMissingWarning: Configuration defaults will be used due to OSError:13 on None warn(ConfigurationMissingWarning(msg))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "execs/reduction_code.py", line 8, in 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 26, in 
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 24, in 
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 7, in 
    from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 35, in 
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my question. As error reported in last line of the output :

```
ImportError: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so)
```

I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20729067/php-shell-command-error-glibcxx-3-4-9-not-found) that the libraries that lampp is using are too old and does not define `GLIBCXX_3.4.9`. So, at first I renamed the `/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6` to `/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6.orig` and then changed the LD_LIBRARY_PATH by changing the command from this :

```
$proc = popen($cmd.' 2>&1', 'r');
```

to this:

```
$proc = popen("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ ".$cmd.' 2>&1', 'r');
```

After I ran my program after this change, another report generated which said that

```
Runtime Error: could not open display
```

After doing some search, I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931376/generating-matplotlib-graphs-without-a-running-x-server) it was the problem of `matplotlib` library. I learned that `matplotlib` library uses X-using backend by default. And X-using backend has problems with few servers. So I followed the answer and inserted these two lines in my `reduction_code.py` program

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

And now, everything is working as expected. Thank you for support.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to make Python's output unbuffered - this is on by default when running from the command line, but otherwise off. The easiest way of fixing this is to add the -u argument to the hashbang at the start of the script:

`#!/usr/bin/python -u`

Comment: Tried it. Still no improvement.

Comment: How about changing the first line of the PHP code to `$cmd = 'python -u execs/reduction_code.py';` ?

Comment: Nothing changes even then.